# Creating a log-likelihood function for an exponential distribution?

Tags: python, function, statistics, distribution

I have been given a certain variable in a dataset that is said to be exponentially distributed and asked to create a log-likelihood function and computing the log-likelihood function of over a range of candidate parameters in the interval (0, 1].(Use at least 100 evenly spaced values in this interval.)

---

```
 def likelihood(scale, data):

     y = len(data)*np.log(scale) - scale*sum(data)
     return y

scale = np.linspace(0,1,100)

L = likelihood(scale, trans_data.Sales_Amount)
print(scale[L.argmax()])
```

plt.plot(scale, L)

---

Unsure if I am on the right track.

Comment: It might be helpful to show the line of reasoning a bit.  Perhaps you could edit the question and explain what maths you think are appropriate to the problem, and then the maths and the Python will be more clearly separable if you see what I mean.